# Solve equation for variable that's both in and out of exponent.

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms

I'm in the process of working on a spreadsheet for a track coach to calculate ASR. [link](https://sprint42.com/2012/11/14/asr-spreadsheet/)

I managed to get to the point where, given time, I can solve for distance.

However, I'd like to be able to calculate the reverse as well, without having to find the nearest value on the spreadsheet and then referencing the time.

Here is the (manipulated) formula I came up with for time to distance.

$$d=t(r+a*e^(-0.013*t))$$

**Can someone help me solve for t?**

I know there's an $ln$ involved somewhere, but I don't know how to deal with a variable that's both inside and outside the exponent.

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%3Dt%28r%2Ba*e%5E%28-0.013*t%29%29) suggests under 'roots' something that looks like t=, but I don't know if that's what I'm looking for.

(not sure on the linear algebra tag, but I guessed 'algebra' was what I'm looking for when it comes to 'solve this equation for this variable)

Comment: You cannot find an algebraic solution using 'normal' algebra. Since you are using a spreadsheet you could use goalseek to find t.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on goalseek, I'll have to read up on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no closed-form solution to this equation.  Numerical solutions (for particular values of the constants) can be found, e.g. using Newton's method, and there can be series solutions. Thus if the $0.013$ is replaced by $s$, there is a series solution in powers of $s$:

$$ t = \frac{d}{a +r}+\frac{d^{2} a}{\left(a +r \right)^{3}} s + \frac{a d^{3} \left(3 a -r \right)}{2 \left(a +r \right)^{5}} s^{2}+ \frac{d^{4} a \left(16 a^{2}-13 a r +r^{2}\right)}{6 \left(a +r \right)^{7}} s^{3}+ \frac{a d^{5} \left(125 a^{3}-171 a^{2} r +39 a r^{2}-r^{3}\right)}{24 \left(a +r \right)^{9}} s^{4}+ \frac{d^{6} a \left(1296 a^{4}-2551 a^{3} r +1091 a^{2} r^{2}-101 a r^{3}+r^{4}\right)}{120\left(a +r \right)^{11}} s^{5}+\ldots
$$
which should converge to a solution for sufficiently small $s$.

Comment: That... looks really ugly... but thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

From a formal point of view, there is an analytical solution. Using the same notations as the ones used by @Robert Israel , we can write
$$e^{-st}=\frac{d-r t}{a t}$$ and the solution would be given in terms of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).

This being said, from a practical point of view, it is not very useful.

Under the same assumptions, what you could do for, at least, the generation of a "reasonable" estimate is to perform one iteration of Newton-like methods (Halley, Householder, ...). Depending on the order $n$ of the method, you would have things like
$$t_{(2)}=\frac{d}{a+r}$$
$$t_{(3)}=\frac{d (a+r)}{a^2-a d s+2 a r+r^2}$$
$$t_{(4)}=\frac{2 \left(a^2 d-a d^2 s+2 a d r+d r^2\right)}{2 a^3-4 a^2 d s+6 a^2 r+a d^2
   s^2-4 a d r s+6 a r^2+2 r^3}$$

Let me try with $s=0.013$, $a=\pi$, $r=e$ and $d=20$. The "exact" solution is $t=4.46864$. The above values would be
$$t_{(2)}=3.41304\qquad t_{(3)}=4.47832\qquad t_{(4)}=4.50790$$

Using $t_0=t_{(2)}$, Newton iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 3.41304 \\
 1 & 4.41371 \\
 2 & 4.46850 \\
 3 & 4.46864
\end{array}
\right)$$